# What doesn't nodejs relate 'this' as the object that encapsulates the function?

Tags: node.js, object, express, callback, this

I wrote the following code in nodejs:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.message = "helloworld";


app.get('/check', function (req,res) {
   res.end("GET request OK");
   console.log(this.message);
});


app.listen(4000);
```

When I run the code and send a GET request, the line:

```
console.log(this.message);
```

prints "undefined".

However, when I change it to:

```
console.log(app.message)
```

I get "helloworld".

I thought that `this` variable should represent the object that invoked the function. If so, why doesn't `this` object include the attribute `.message` ?

Answer (score 0):

`this` can be whatever the author of the library intends it to be. It could be the `app` instance or it could be the `global` object.

In this case, it appears it's the `global` object.

As a sidenote too, it's not recommended to add expando properties to an existing library like that.

Comment: OK. How do I determine the value of 'this' ?